# How to use a business loss to convert a traditional to a Roth IRA?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, business, roth-conversion, losses

I have an annual business loss on a C-corp business I own. Is it possible to use that loss to convert traditional pretax IRA funds over to Roth IRA?

Comment: Is the loss going to be reported on the 2017 return?

Answer (score 3):

Nope.  Rolling over an IRA from trad to Roth counts as an IRA distribution. IRA distributions are *not* capital gains and are taxed as salary income at salary rates.

Totally separate from that is your capital gain/loss reporting.  You total up all your capital gains and losses for the year.  If you lost more than $3000, you must cap your capital loss deduction at $3000 and carryforward the loss to next year (where it can offset next year's capital gains).

Even so, taking a capital loss from *your own C-corp* is a little complicated.  **A C-corp's profits and losses *do not* pass through**  like a proprietorship or passthru LLC.  If it did, *that would make it an [S-corp](https://www.inc.com/guides/201103/s-corp-vs-llc.html)*.  A single-shareholder C-corp is not a [disregarded entity](https://www.thebalance.com/disregarded-entity-definition-and-background-398223) like a single-member-LLC.

So to take a tax loss on your personal taxes for a C-corp, you have to have a taxable event -- you need to **sell stock**.  Then you can take the cost basis (what you paid for the stock) minus the sale proceeds (what you got paid for the stock) and that is your tax loss.  Disbanding the company and selling off its assets to pay its debts is a valid way to "sell stock".

Regardless, no manner of liquidating a single-shareholder C-corp will allow you to offset more than $3000 of income, so it's no help to offset IRA distributions.